# How to list/download the recursive dependencies of a debian package?

Tags: dependencies, package, debian

I need to list/download all the recursive dependencies of a debian package.

Suppose i need to install package a.deb and it depends on package b.deb and again package b.deb depends on package c.deb.

I need to download all the recursive dependent packages so that they can be installed on some other machine without any internet access.

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468753/recursive-dependencies

Answer (score 108):

For some reason `apt-rdepends` did not work for me (when searching the 'docker-engine' package, it missed the dependency onto `libltdl7` which was introduced with `docker-engine 1.11.1-0`). **UPD** Supposedly owing to the fact that `apt-rdepends` doesn't follow and doesn't list Recommends by default. And doesn't follow virtual packages.

So I came up with following command suite.

### Recursively list dependencies

```
$ apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances <your-package-here> | grep "^\w" | sort -u
```

(you obviously have to change `<your-package-here>` at the end of the line with the package you want to  analyze)

The key here is the `--recurse` option. Unfortunately, you cannot specify the content you want (or I did not find the way) so you need to turn off all unwanted dependencies to keep only "dependencies". It is a bit verbose and hard to remember!

From the apt-cache man page:

> Per default the depends and rdepends print all dependencies

### Download those dependencies

So in order to download those dependencies, run following command which will download them into the current working directory:

```
$ apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances <your-package-here> | grep "^\w" | sort -u)
```

### Optionally, to install those dependencies

This extends slightly the asked question, but it seems to match the *intent* of the question.

You need to build the *index* of the just downloaded packages. This is done from the same folder where all .deb where downloaded:

```
$ dpkg-scanpackages . | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Then just copy that folder (all .deb + the Packages.gz file) to the target system which does not have Internet access and add the folder to the APT source list.

```
$ echo "deb file:<your folder here> ./" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
```

### Et voilà

On a system w/o Internet access, I can install a package (Docker in my example) and its dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Comment: Once you know the dependencies you need, you can edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add /etc/apt/preferences.d/somename.pref, if the machine that is offline has a newer (it won't work for older, I tried) version of Ubuntu. See: medium.com/@george.shuklin/…

Comment: This is great! Thanks a bunch! I'd like to add that I had to make the following changes for the installation to work on my Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install:

echo "deb [allow-insecure=yes] file:<your folder here> ./" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

and

sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated docker-engine

Comment: You can also use "deb [trusted=yes] file:/your/folder/path/here/ ./"

With that I haven't had the need to use "--allow-unauthenticated" in my apt commands.

Comment: Also, user might want to omit `--no-recommends`, since they're installed by default.

Comment: I get the error when I try to do apt-get update "E: The repository 'file:/home/myusernamehere/Pulled_Installers ./ Release' does not have a Release file.  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and therefore is disabled by default.   When I tried to add [allow-insecure=yes] after the deb, then when I try to update I get E: Conflicting values set for option ALLOW_INSECURE regarding source <set> <unset> E: The list of sources could not be read. @YannVo

Comment: I actually got the apt-update to work, but when I try to install any given package (in this case, libfftw3-dev), it fails unable to target its dependencies.  Those dependencies are in the target folder that I made the Packages.gz from.  I did get an error at one point about not having a Release. @YannVo

Comment: @Jibril I can reproduce your issue but I am not sure how to resolve it, sorry!
If you find the answser, don't hesitate to share it!

Comment: @Jibril The solution to `E: The repository ... does not have a Release file` was trusting the sources.list entry `echo "deb [trusted=yes] file:<your folder here> ./ | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`. Found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository#comment1865312_176546)

Comment: When I run this command, I get what looks like overlapping dependencies. Can somebody explain what this means? For instance, I get `python3, python3.8, python3.8:i386, python3.8-minimal, python3.8-minimal:i386` among the dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `apt-rdepends` for getting all the dependencies for a package recursively. And by piping the result to grep you can have only the package names and omit unneeded information.

**Example**:

```
 $ apt-rdepends cowsay | grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

**Output**:

```
cowsay
perl
libbz2-1.0
libc6
libgcc1
gcc-4.9-base
multiarch-support
libdb5.3
libgdbm3
dpkg
liblzma5
libselinux1
libpcre3
tar
libacl1
libattr1
zlib1g
install-info
perl-base
perl-modules
```

You can then download those packages using `apt-get download $package` and install them offline on your machine.

By default, `apt` installs Recommends, so you might want to run `apt-rdepends` like so:

```
apt-rdepends -f Depends,PreDepends,Recommends -s Depends,PreDepends,Recommends cowsay
```

Since `apt-rdepends` by default follows and shows only Depends, PreDepends.

Answer (score 2):

As [midihenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3356505/midihenry) pointed out - install the apt-rdepends package and then run this

```
$ apt-rdepends gcc | awk '$1 ~ /^Depends:/{print $2}' | xargs apt-get download
```

this line will get all dependencies recursively and, looking at the second pipe, will download all the packages by name from the stdio, which is what the line -

`awk $1 ~ /^Depends:/{print $2}` does. prints out the names of packages. If you run these commands additively, you'll see what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash command to download a debian package along with its recursive dependencies. Unlike the other answers, this command wont fail if one of the packages returned by `apt-rdepends` cannot be downloaded.

```sh
for PKG in $(apt-rdepends <package> | grep -v "^ ");  do apt download $PKG; done
```

Comment: The loop is kind of unnecessary; `apt download $(apt-rdepends "$1" | grep -v '^ ')` but the requirement to install a separate utility `apt-rdepends` just for this is also kind of unattractive. (Separately, [probably don't use upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization))