# How to list/download the recursive BUILD dependencies of a debian package?

Tags: package, dependencies, debian, apt

I've recently learned that one can use `apt` to download sources and easily amend, re-build, and install the package locally from [Cinnamon volume step and media keys](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=312162).

```
# Download the sources
apt source cinnamon-settings-daemon
cd cinnamon-settings-daemon-4.4.0+tricia
# Then install the build dependencies
apt build-dep cinnamon-settings-daemon
#Then build from the modified sources
apt build
Install the modified deb file (again note the version string may differ for different Cinnamon versions)
apt deb ~/cinnamon-settings-daemon_4.4.0+tricia_amd64.deb
```

I now also want to be able to just download all packages needed for `apt build-dep` as for binary package install [How to list/download the recursive dependencies of a debian package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008193/how-to-list-download-the-recursive-dependencies-of-a-debian-package/41428445#41428445). However, when I've tried to use `--download-only` and then install debs files, it resulted in several other files needed:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libarchive-cpio-perl libcupsfilters-dev libicu66:i386 libltdl-dev
  libmail-sendmail-perl libpng-tools libpulse0:i386 libsys-hostname-long-perl
```

Even `$ apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances cinnamon-settings-daemon | grep "^\w" | sort -u` does not list e.g. `libarchive-cpio-perl` and also `--download-only` when I tried to substitute empty dmkg status file (`$(apt-config shell STATUS Dir::State::status)`) and downloaded ~500 files, not ~100, that "additional" file(s) is(are) still missing.

Added 1:
I added `--no-install-recommends` to `apt install debs` and now only two `i386` remained in additional not downloaded:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libicu66:i386 libpulse0:i386
```

Any idea what is so special about them? These are the only `i386` mentioned, 1st one listed in `apt cache` above. 2nd not listed, so combining two deb sets is not a way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded debs with dpkg status file corresponding to a system with less packages installed than one where I tried to install later. I assumed it ensures all required are downloaded. However, as I received an answer after facing same issue with regular (not build, sources) packages, it is not so: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684975/446998. Additionally installed packages included some i386 architecture packages with corresponding amd64 packages among downloaded debs, so i386 required upgrade too when amd64 were installed as needed to be kept in sync.