How to get recursive list of all dependency packages of not installed .deb file
Context
I'm generating a .deb file as part of a build process. This .deb file properly declares all its dependencies and can be installed via the typical apt-get or apt install <package.deb> so long as the box is connected to the Internet.
Problem
I also need ability to deliver the full package to air-gapped boxes.  That implies that all dependencies also need to be included in the delivery.
What I tried...
I attempted to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469489/1556108, which would do just fine.   Idea is that, as part of build process, run it, let it download all recursive dependencies, then tar the whole thing, and resulting archive is what to be distributed to air-gapped machines that then can be extracted and all packages are installed, ensuring proper and full installation of the package on such boxes.
The problem is that apt-rdepends only examines installed packages, and I can't seem to find a way to point it to examine the .deb file instead.  Further complicating the problem is that installing the package inside the build docker container just to extract the dependencies is a) hacky as it effectively pollutes build environment, and b) not actually possible because package tries to run systemd service that docker container doesn't -- nor should -- have.
I also looked into apt-cache rdepends, and into dpkg options, and it doesn't seem any of those can analyze and do what apt-rdepends would do for installed package.  Maybe I missed something.
Question
How can I do the equivalent of apt-rdepends <package> but on <package.deb> instead?

For this kind of thing, my go-to is to use python-apt.  I've used it to examine dependencies of available packages, but I expect you could add your package file's metadata (or at a pinch, generate a Packages file from it using dpkg-scanpackages and read that in).
